# Can't install python modules with pip on Manjaro Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, manjaro

I'm on Manjaro Linux KDE and every time I try to install a module with pip it gives me this error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR:

    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                              
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main 
        status = self.run(options, args)                                                            
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 279, in run   
        session = self.get_default_session(options)                                                 
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 74, in get_default_session                                                                                     
        self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))                            
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 84, in _build_session                                                                                          
        session = PipSession(                                                                       
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 241, in __init__                                                                                               
        self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()                                                   
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent                                                                                             
        zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),                                
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution            
        return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)                                   
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution            
        self.version(),                                                                             
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 737, in version                       
        self.lsb_release_attr('release'),                                                           
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr              
        return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')                                            
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 552, in __get__                       
        ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)                                              
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info            
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)                                       
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output                            
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,                            
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 145, in __new__                 
        process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)                 
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 121, in create_process          
        shlex.split(command),                                                                       
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 311, in split                                        
        return list(lex)                                                                            
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 300, in __next__                                     
        token = self.get_token()                                                                    
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 109, in get_token                                    
        raw = self.read_token()                                                                     
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 140, in read_token                                   
        nextchar = self.instream.read(1)                                                            
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'                                          
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 75, in main
        return command.main(cmd_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 105, in main
        return self._main(args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 224, in _main
        self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 143, in handle_pip_version_check
        session = self._build_session(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 84, in _build_session
        session = PipSession(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 241, in __init__
        self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent
        zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution
        return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution
        self.version(),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 737, in version
        self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr
        return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 552, in __get__
        ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
        process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
        shlex.split(command),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 311, in split
        return list(lex)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
        token = self.get_token()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
        raw = self.read_token()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
        nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Also, when I try to run a program where I imported selenium or any other installed module from pip it gives me the same error.
This is my pip version: pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try using `pip3` instead of `pip`, also are you using the system's default python interpreter?

Comment: Hi, I tried using pip3 and it gives me the same error. Yes I'm using the system's default interpreter.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the system's default python interpreter. I recommend you to set up a python virtual environment and try again.  Use the following command to creates a virtualenv in the specified folder/path - `python -m venv <path-to-myenv>` Then then go into your virtualenv folder and cd into Scripts then reun `activate`. Now you should be inside your  virtualenv. Now try reinstalling everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short use yay in the console:

```
yay pacman -S python-LIBRARYNAME
```

Long story:
Pip will not work on Manjaro/Arch without a virtual environment.
You can try installing a package IF it is on the AUR repository by writing this in the console:

```
sudo pacman -S python-LIBRARYNAME
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).